# Profile does not have access to: processbuilderaction

Tags: apex, process-builder, visual-workflow

Unit test is failing with the error "Profile does not have access to: processbuilderaction".

Context:
Unit test case, runs as user profile and creates a record on custom object.
There is a process, which gets invoked on new record creation of custom object and among various actions, one action is to invoke a flow.

Could this be related to Sprint '21? tried granting explicit access on the flow in question to the profile, but didn't help.

Comment: Is there any apex code being used in flow or PB?

Comment: thanks @Ayub for quick response. I found PB is invoking apex method from class "ProcessBuilderAction". Issue is resolved after granting access on this class to user's profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

processbuilderaction looks like an Apex Class. Have you granted the specific user profile access to this specific apex class?

Lots of people reporting similar issues today - all relating to "Disable Rules for Enforcing Explicit Access to Apex Classes" being enforced in Spring '21 release over the weekend. See Known Issue for alternative suggested resolution: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002BLeLQAW

Comment: Thanks @Claire Jones for adding detailed explanation. I found PB is invoking apex method from class "ProcessBuilderAction". Name is misleading, very generic in nature. Issue is resolved after granting access on this class to user's profile.